# JavaScript Result

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript. Recently I was asked what the result of the following code is. I'm not totally sure how to answer this question. Can anyone provide what they think the answer is?

```
(function f(x, y, m) {
    if (m > 0) { return f( y, x + y, m - 1 ); }
    return y;
}(1, 2, 7) );
```

Comment: Run it in the console and find out. It is basic recursion.

Comment: Execute it by hand on a piece of paper, writing the values of the variables in each step. That's how you learn to understand how functions work.

Answer (score 2):

result

```
55
```

Why, first because I launched in the console. This a recursion, teh stop condicion is the m, that if look always is reduced by 1. This mind that he call it 8 times, the last one return direcly the second param.

This mind that the only important here is the second param, that is call by `x + y` and Y moving to the first param.

```
(((((((1 + 2 ) + 2 ) + 3 ) + 5) + 8  ) + 13 ) + 21)
```

That is a fibonacci sequence starting in 1 and 2 :) This function provide the position m + 2 (you provide the 2 first numbers) in the fibonacci sequence starting in x and y

```
1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number

Comment: Curious that the problem went with `(1, 2, 7)` and not `(1, 1, 8)` . . .

Comment: http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/Fibonacci/fibGen.html#section1.1

Comment: I guess I was just surprised to see the numbers start so far into the series . . . usually you see the Fibonacci numbers start with either "0, 1, 1 . . ." or "1, 1, 2, . . .".  It just struck me as odd to see it started as "1, 2, 3 . . .".   On a side note, it's interesting to see this represented programatically . . . I hadn't really ever thought of it before.

Comment: @SouthernBoy If you are happy with this response, please you mark it as valid. If not, you feel free to add any comments to search the optimal solution.